# View the CTAS query that created a table in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

Is it possible to view the query that created a given table, in oracle sql? (I lost the original code).
EDIT: I am actually searching for the query that generated *the rows* of the table, i.e. the CTAS statement "*create table X as select ...*".
As far as I understood, there is no way to do this.

Comment: Just to pick a nit, queries do not create tables.   Tables are created by DDL (Data Definition Language.  Queries are DML (Data Manipulation Language)

Answer (score 3):

Use `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`. For example:

```
SQL> set long 10000
SQL>
SQL> SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('TABLE', table_name, owner)
  2    FROM all_tables
  3   WHERE     owner = 'SCOTT'
  4         AND table_name = 'EMP';

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',TABLE_NAME,OWNER)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."EMP"
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10),
        "JOB" VARCHAR2(9),
        "MGR" NUMBER(4,0),
        "HIREDATE" DATE,
        "SAL" NUMBER(7,2),
        "COMM" NUMBER(7,2),
        "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0),
         CONSTRAINT "PK_EMP" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPNO")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USER_DATA"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USER_DATA"


SQL>
```

Alternatively, use some GUI tool which lets you see that info in a matter of a few clicks.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however my question was not clear, I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

If "query that created a given table" means table was created with CTAS, for example like this

```
create table some_table as select ... ;
```

Then you may use v$sql hoping the query is still there

```
select * from v$sql where upper(sql_text) like 'CREATE TABLE%';
```

Comment: That would only work as long as the sql is still in the memory pool, which is highly unlikely.

Comment: @EdStevens That was exactly was I meant saying "hoping the query is still there".

Comment: That's interesting, however I get "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

Comment: @Giuseppe that most probably means you don"t have access to the v$sql. Perhaps asking DBA for help might help you out